# How can I both show and hide a form with same key?

Tags: c#, forms

I am making an RPG game with forms and I can't figure out how to show and hide a particular form with only one key. For example when I press the "C" key I want it to show me the form with the PlayerInfo panel, and when I press "C" again I want it to hide it.

```
private void KeyPress(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        PlayerInfo playerInfo = new PlayerInfo(this);
        bool visible = false;

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.C)
        {
            if (visible == false)
            {
                playerInfo.Show();
                visible = true;
            } 
        }

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.C)
        {
            if (visible)
            {
                playerInfo.Hide();
                visible = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an if/else statement, right now both if's are getting called so you end up showing and then hiding it in the same call when you hit the key

```
bool visible = false;

private void KeyPress(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    PlayerInfo playerInfo = new PlayerInfo(this);


    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.C)
    {
        if (visible == false)
        {
            playerInfo.Show();
            visible = true;
        } 
        else if (visible)
        {
            playerInfo.Hide();
            visible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: Sorry, I didn't notice that your visible variable was a local variable. You need to make this a class variable, and set it on construction of your object. If you initialize it in your callback you'll always be setting it to false.

Comment: Good answer - but the `if (visible)` is redundant (it can just be an `else`).

Comment: This won't work, you are always setting visible to false.

Comment: Change the scope of the `visible` variable and it will work

Comment: Yep, sorry I didn't realize visible was getting set in your callback, as the other commentators have pointed out you need to move out of the scope of the method so you aren't setting it every time the callback gets called.

Comment: Still not working, now it needs to hit the key two times to show the form. Weird.

Comment: `playerInfo` will instantiate in each key press. so it may not be a good solution

Comment: Hahahahaha Still not working but accepted as answer....! Compare both http://pastebin.com/E102x9EB

Answer (score 1):

I would add a method and a property in PlayerInfo class, called `toggle`

```
 public class PlayerInfo { 
       // your stuff
       public bool IsVisible {get;set;}
       public void Toggle() {
             if (IsVisible)
                   Hide()
             else
                   Show()
             IsVisible = !IsVisible
       }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Using your code you will always  get it's visibility true until u make
>   `visible` as global variable. Probably `playerInfo` too be global, else it will be a new instance every time.

Global declaration:

```
bool visible = false;
PlayerInfo playerInfo = new PlayerInfo(this);
```

`KeyPress` Method signature:

```
private void KeyPress(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
 if (e.KeyCode == Keys.C)
    {
        if (!visible)
        {
            playerInfo.Show();
            visible = true;
        } 
        else
        {
            playerInfo.Hide();
            visible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I moved the boolean outside the method and its still not working. Now it requires to key presses to show the form, but it doesn't hide it at all.

Comment: Moving Boolean variable alone will not result in a good result. since `playerInfo` will instantiate in each key press. so you need to make it's scope to global. see the updates in my answer

Comment: When I move the playerInfo outside the method it gives me ObjectDisposed exception.

Comment: I figured out where the issues was. Now its working. Thanks!